# Multiple switches to independently control the counters

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, simulation, counter

I just started studying electrical engineering this semester, and I'm currently working on the following counter to count the vacancy and occupied bed counts in a hospital for my school project:[image]

The UP and DOWN pins of the two 74190 for the LSBs are shorted so that when one section counts up, the other counts down. The issue I have with the circuit is that when I used more switches to control the counter, both counters always count down no matter what. [image]

I'm not sure if I need some gates for the switches and I appreciate any help on solving the issue. I'm sorry for my bad English as it is not my first language. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a very strange set-up with your push buttons.

With the set-up you have there, when one of the buttons is pressed then R1 is shorted to ground, causing 0V to all of the UP and DOWN inputs.
You need one pull-up per signal.

The more common way of connecting buttons like this is to only let the button connect to 0V, not to flip between 5V and 0V. Something like this:
[image: Improved schematic]

Also you will probably have to add some filtering to remove contact bounce. Without any filtering, your circuit will likely count more than once for every button press.